# Can't activate WPS-Office in Ubutu

Tags: wps-office

I bought a subscription from wps office to enable the premium features and it worked well on windows. Now I switched to Ubuntu and installed wps but there's no field to enter the product key to activate it. There is no option to upgrade.
I have Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (the latest LTS).
I downloaded wps from the wps-homepage Deb-Package and installed it with the command "sudo dpkg -i wps-office_11.1.0.11664.XA_amd64.deb"

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: @guiverc Thank you sir. I wrote the wrong OS release (a typo) but now I corrected it

Answer (score 2):

I sent an E-Mail to WPS explaining this problem. They said it's because WPS-Office Premium is not supported for Linux, that is why there is no field to enter the product key in the Linux version of WPS.

In the Linux version of wps you only have the free features.

So don't buy wps premium, if you're using linux